# Is it possible to parse headings from a Markdown file using showdown?

Tags: javascript, markdown, showdown

Recently I came across a [Python cheat sheet](https://gto76.github.io/python-cheatsheet/) that was implemented with [showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown). It loads the Markdown from GitHub and then uses showdown to render that response to HTML. Since the cheat sheet is rather long I'd like to add a floating table of contents. To do that, I need the top-level headings.

Ideally, I'd like showdown to provide me with a list of headings from the Markdown to render the table of contents. I poked around in the Chrome developer console when viewing the cheat sheet and it appears that the showdown API has a small API surface. After looking at the showdown docs and searching for more detailed API documentation I couldn't find a way to achieve what I wanted.

It seems like it might just be more efficient for me to get what I need from the HTML after the call to `converter.makeHtml(text)`, but I thought it was worthwhile asking this question. If there are alternative Markdown engines that offer this capability I'd switch.